# Downloading only first item from web service - Android

Tags: android, xml, for-loop

I want to download items from a web service to Android app (Web service output - XML). I'm using Android Download Manager class for downloading part.

When I click download button  , it only downloads the first item from XML list. This is what I tried. Help me to download all files.

```
  try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/WebService/gettext.aspx? ");       
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");

        iname = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        itime = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        int listlength = nodeList.getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            itime[i] = new TextView(this);
            iname[i] = new TextView(this);

            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
            NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("iname");
            Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
            nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
            iname[i].setText(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            NodeList itimeList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("itime");
            Element websiteElement = (Element) itimeList.item(0);
            itimeList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
            itime[i].setText("ITime = "
                    + ((Node) itimeList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            imgName=iname[i].getText().toString().trim();
//Image folder.
                dwnload_file_path = "http://localhost/WebService/Images/"+URLEncoder.encode(iname[i].getText().toString(),"UTF-8");

            String servicestring = Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE;

            downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(servicestring);


            Uri uri = Uri.parse(dwnload_file_path);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);


             request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Download",imgName.toString());

            downloadId = downloadmanager.enqueue(request);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("EEEEEEEEE "+ e.toString());
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"35",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This is the XML output from web service.

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<image>
<iname>abdf.jpg</iname>
<itime>10000</itime>
<iname>bcdf.jpg</iname>
<itime>10000</itime>
<iname>cd.jpg</iname>
<itime>10000</itime>
<iname>efe.jpg</iname>
<itime>10000</itime>
<iname>ggef.jpg</iname>
<itime>10000</itime>
<iname>hiefef.jpg</iname>
<itime>10000</itime>
<iname>mmfer.jpg</iname>
<itime>10000</itime>
<iname>nnnef.jpg</iname>
<itime>10000</itime>
<iname>erer.jpg</iname>
<itime>10000</itime>
</image>
```

Comment: try to replace 0 with i, it may work- nameList.item(i)

Comment: @DeepanshuHarbola- Thank you for answering. I tried. But same results. only downloading the first item.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `nodeList.get(0)` to get list of elements under `<image>` Tag and that should be above `for` loop.

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");
iname = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
itime = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
int listlength = nodeList.getLength();
    if(listlength > 0) {
          Node node = nodeList.item(0);
          NodeList imageList = doc.getElementsByTagName("iname");  
            for (int i = 0; i < imageList.getLength(); i++) {
                  // do stull with all your image names
             }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What do you mean by 'do stull with all your image names?' Do I have to inser this code inside' itime[i] = new TextView(this);' the for loop?